# HBase : Retention policy for HBase Export

Tags: amazon-s3, hbase

We are using **HBase 1.2.3**. I am trying to configure HBase backup functionality (Export functionality in 1.2.3 version).

Am able to successfully export table on S3. Both full & incremental backups.

On S3, all the files goes in default root/base folder and a mapping file (not sure in which language) goes inside specified folder.

[image]

2 Ques

- How can i set retention policy to keep backups for x days. I wrote custom code to delete files/folders under specific folder but how to determine which block files are for which table and whether for full backup or incremental
- Can we change the way HBase stores backup file. When we take backup on file system, it stores backup files under same folder. Can we achieve same result on S3?